# Ehcache search API with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

Could I search over a second level cache with a ehcache search API?

If I fill a cache with objects directly using `put()` method it is possible to search using SearchAttribute. When I'm trying to query a second level Hibernate cache I'm stuck at assembling an entity from disassembled state of an object in ehcache.

```
    public class TestExtr implements AttributeExtractor {

    @Override
    public Object attributeFor(Element element, String arg1)
            throws AttributeExtractorException {

        return element.?()  ; //how to cast its value to Employee?
    }
}
```

Example of my entity

```
      public class Employee implements Serializable {
        private int id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int salary;

   // getters and setters
    }
```

`Element element` value for the second level cache is:

```
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy$Item@6b8efd7c 
    key = test.Employee#1383    
    CacheEntry(test.Employee)[aaaaa,dd,77]
```